# Why is the counter decrementing correctly but the countdown is not?

Tags: html, angularjs, math

Here is my angular code to define a countdown timer for my website:

```js
function AlbumCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.counter = new Date("Nov 30, 2017 09:00:00").getTime() - new Date().getTime();
  $scope.onTimeout = function() {
    $scope.counter--;
    var distance = $scope.counter;
    $scope.countdown = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + "d " +
      Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)) + "h " +
      Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)) + "m " +
      Math.floor(((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)) + "s ";
    if ($scope.counter > 0) {
      mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
    } else {
      alert("Time is up!");
    }
  }

  var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script> <!-- added for a working snippet -->


<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc11.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
    {{counter}} {{countdown}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The 'counter' appears to decrement correctly on my page but the 'countdown' stays fixed and shows the correct value only on page load or refresh. For example, I get the following output as time passes:

```
    1115148833 12d 21h 45m 48s
    1115148745 12d 21h 45m 48s
    1115148693 12d 21h 45m 48s
```

What exactly is going wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Holy cow that's an old version of angular is it okay to be using 1.6 to show an example?  Don't see anything obviously wrong with the code but that is a severely out dated version anything before 1.2 had a lot of problems and they are up to 1.6.6 for the latest (in the 1.x branch) with lots of fixes in between, worth bumping if it isn't a big existing project.

Comment: wheres the script tag for the controller?

Comment: I'm a newbie so please excuse my ignorance. I was under the impression that you do not need one. The counter seems to work as expected. If I'm wrong, please provide an example of what is expected as the controller tag.

Comment: No worries I added an answer to show some more up to date conventions for writing bigger apps you will be served well by checking out the style guide linked in my answer, as other answers explain the issue is with the math on the seconds (console logged that to see it wasn't changing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1

```js
// Declare a "main" module for the single page application
// second argument to module is an array of dependencies your module
// uses (examples: ui-router ui-bootstrap etc., 'ng' module is assumed as a dependency)
angular.module('myApp', [])


//Defining a service on the module allows you to encapsulate some functionality
//Injecting the angular $timeout service from the 'ng' module and defining
//a new service.  This object gets initialized the first time it's
//referenced and stays alive until the application/page is refreshed.
.service("CountdownService", function($timeout){
  //Define an object to attach properties and functions to and return for
  //use elsewhere in the app
  var countdownService = {};
  
  //Basically the functional code you had already adjusted the
  //seconds to just use %60 since some sort of issue with the existing math
  // %60 should give remainder after dividing by 60 and appears the "distance"
  // was moving at 1 second per second not 1000, so removed the 1000 factors
  countdownService.counter = new Date("Nov 30, 2017 09:00:00").getTime() - new Date().getTime();
  countdownService.onTimeout = function() {
    countdownService.counter--;
    var distance = countdownService.counter;
    
    var newValue = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) + "d " +
      Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)) + "h " +
      Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)) + "m " +
      Math.floor((distance % (60)) ) + "s ";
    countdownService.countdown = newValue;
      
      console.log(Math.floor((distance % (60))) + "s ");
    if (countdownService.counter > 0) {
      mytimeout = $timeout(countdownService.onTimeout, 1000);
    } else {
      alert("Time is up!");
    }
  }

  var mytimeout = $timeout(countdownService.onTimeout, 1000);
  return countdownService;
})

//Now the controller just has the new service injected it uses "this"
//instead of scope in the ng-controller we use "controllerAs" syntax
//so we don't need to use the scope (angular 2 hides the scope so good
//to just get used to not using it)
.controller("TestCtrl", function(CountdownService){
  this.CountdownService = CountdownService;
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl as testCtrl">
    {{testCtrl.CountdownService.counter}} {{testCtrl.CountdownService.countdown}}
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.js"></script> <!-- added for a working snippet -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting . Your Math.floor function is giving round figure of the fraction and your fraction number changes so minutely with counter , only seconds string  decreases from one number when counter comes to 1095904999. So you are not able to notice the change , see yourself :

```js
function AlbumCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.counter = new Date("Nov 30, 2017 09:00:00").getTime() - new Date().getTime();
  $scope.onTimeout = function() {
    --$scope.counter;
    var distance = $scope.counter;
   $scope.countdown = $scope.counter/ (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) + "d " +
  ( $scope.counter% (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60) + "h " +
 ( $scope.counter% (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)+ "m " +
 (( $scope.counter% (1000 * 60)) / 1000) + "s ";
    if ($scope.counter > 0) {
      mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
    } else {
      alert("Time is up!");
    }
  }

  var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script> <!-- added for a working snippet -->


<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc11.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
    {{counter}} {{countdown}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For demonstration purposes(to simplify correctness of answer checking) I set destination `date` to 1 day and 2 hours later from now:

```js
function AlbumCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(date.getHours() + 2);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);

  $scope.counter = date.getTime() - new Date().getTime();
  $scope.onTimeout = function() {
    $scope.counter = $scope.counter - 1000;
    var ost = $scope.counter;

    function GetPart(koef) {
      koef *= 1000;
      var res = Math.floor(ost / koef);
      ost = ost - res * koef;
      return res;
    }

    var days = GetPart(60 * 60 * 24);
    var hours = GetPart(60 * 60);
    var min = GetPart(60);
    var sec = GetPart(1);

    $scope.countdown = days + "d " + hours + "h " + min + "m " + sec + "s ";

    if ($scope.counter > 0)
      mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
    else
      alert("Time is up!");
  }

  var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- added for a working snippet -->


<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc11.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="AlbumCtrl">
    {{countdown}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```